# How to Find the value of a trigonometric function if other very complicated trigonometric equation is given?

Tags: trigonometry

> Q)If $\operatorname{sin}\alpha+\operatorname{cos}\alpha=\frac{\sqrt7}2$, $0 \lt \alpha \lt\frac{\pi}{6}, then \operatorname{tan}\frac{\alpha}2 $ is:
> (1)$\sqrt{7}-2$
> (2)$(\sqrt{7}-2)/3$
> (3)$-\sqrt{7}+2$
> (4)$(-\sqrt{7}+2)/3$

i did this question by two ways but both the was were getting so complex however on solving them completely which took $4.25$ pages the answers were ridiculously different.

### $I^{st}$ Method:

squaring both sides $$(\operatorname{sin}\alpha+\operatorname{cos}\alpha)^2=\frac{7}4=1+ \operatorname{sin}2\alpha=\frac 74\implies\operatorname{sin}2\alpha=\frac 34\implies\operatorname{cos}2\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}$$
$$\text{hence, }\operatorname{tan}2\alpha=\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}\implies 3tan^2\alpha+2\sqrt{7}tan \alpha -3=0\implies tan\alpha=\frac{\surd7 \pm 4}3 $$

no from this if i want to calculate the value of $\tan\alpha/2  $   then you can think how different the answer could be!

### $II^{nd} $ Method

$$1+2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=\frac74\implies \sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha=\frac{9}{64}$$
$$64\sin^4\alpha-64\sin^2\alpha+9=0\implies \sin^2\alpha=\frac{64\pm 64\sqrt{7}}{2\times 64}$$

even from this you can have the idea how different the answer will be so different because the value of $$\tan\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{64 \pm16\surd7}{64 \mp 16\surd7}}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t=\tan⁡\fracα2$ then 
$$
\cosα = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\text{ and }\sinα = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}
$$
so that 
$$
a=\cosα+\sinα=\frac{1-t^2+2t}{1+t^2}\iff (1+a)t^2 - 2t +a-1=0\\
\iff ((a+1)t-1)^2 -1 + (a^2-1) \\
\iff t=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{2-a^2}}{a+1}=\frac{a-1}{1\mp\sqrt{2-a^2}}
$$
and with $a=\frac{\sqrt7}2$
$$
t=\frac{2a-2}{2\mp\sqrt{8-(2a)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt7-2}{2\pm 1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You need the [tangent half angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula). It says that $\tan(\alpha/2)=\frac{1-\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$. The link has some other versions.

Answer (score 1):

Good news: they are the same!
$$\sqrt{\frac{64 \pm16\surd7}{64 \mp 16\surd7}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{64 \pm16\surd7}{64 \mp 16\surd7}}\sqrt{\frac{64 \pm16\surd7}{64 \pm 16\surd7}}$$
$$=\frac{64 \pm16\surd7}{16\sqrt{9}}$$
$$=\frac{4 \pm\surd7}{3}$$